# Select from database and limit with software, or limit on database (mysql)

Tags: php, mysql, optimization, query-optimization

I am working on a social network platform which allows users to comment on posts.

And I have came up with a dilemma that whether I should select all the comments for each post (when loading the page) and then use the software to cut it down, or should I limit the result using the mysql query.

The reason for this dilemma is that, mysql does its own optimization and query/result caching, and if I limit the output, query caching will become useless(or maybe not?), but if I don't, I will have a software overhead, as well as getting more data than needed.

The question may sound like this one [MYSQL and the LIMIT clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818571/mysql-and-the-limit-clause/) which refers to limit 1, but in my case, the number of results can be from 0 to 3000 (or even more). The limit is usually 3, but will be different if users want to see more comments.

I should mention that the query does have an ORDER BY id DESC clause and its a SELECT * (it must be). Basically, SELECT * FROM table WHERE postid='$variable' ORDER BY id DESC.

I also have to mention that the software has been running fine for over 2 years, but I'm in the process of optimizing it. So, any help would be great.

EDIT: **TL;DR** The main question is this: Is having one database query and then using software to use part of it better than requesting the exact data needed (with limit clause) ?

Comment: Why not just test it? You case sounds specific enough that you need to try it for yourself

Comment: both methods work fine, except that I have no exact way of finding out the performance difference. And some expert opinion would really help.

Comment: And also I should add that it is not easy to test. You need thousands of users to get on the system, make variable posts with variable lengths and then make thousands of comments and then write down the time it takes to load to compare them. So, basically its not really possible to test.

Comment: Sina - First - if it is not a problem - dont fix it!. There are many tools available for benchmarking - first use EXPLAIN queries so you can analyze the results on how the mysql optimization engine is doing this. If you need thousands of users, write a test that does it and stop whining - are you a programmer or not?

Comment: I am not whining. I have been a programmer for over 10 years, and when you have 500 online users, loading 10 posts, with 5-10 comments each, and you want it to be very fast, it is not an easy task. you can always have bad code, and say if it works, its fine, but when the load is high on the server, you need to optimize the code or pay a lot to distribute the load. The latter cannot be afforded, and my question is mainly this: (Will update the main question)

Answer (score 0):

If both method works fine, i would recommend letting the database do the limiting.

This would allow you to move some processing to the database, so in future it will be easier to separate and beef up the servers.

Just imagine, if the number of comments balloons. just move the db to a beefier server and performance will improve.

Comment: The thing is that, as you may know, with social networks like twitter, fb, ... , only the latest posts are seen, commented on, and then will be forgotten.
So, what really matters is that same process running for many users. I can't do caching as it changes rapidly. And also, I really like to know if loading all and letting mysql cache it, can have any performance benefit than loading only whatever you need.

Comment: Based on what you said. you can't cache it on the database, and also not at http. so why not just reduce memory usage by limiting at the db. if not your php will need to load all 1000 comments even if you just want to display 5. let the database handle the data filtering as that is what a database is optimized for.

Comment: Another is, don't use relational tables. look at some of the nosql solutions like terracotta or big tables. most sites like Facebook or twitter are using that as you can scale that easily by adding hardware.

Comment: I am not sure how exactly can NoSQL be beneficial here. And the client's aim is not to add more hardware, and lower the cpu/ram required as much as possible. We are already using memcached to cache data as much as possible, but comments cannot be cached due to their nature. I already made a switch to limit the output, but really like to know if mysql's internal query/result caching could be beneficial by loading all. As in most cases, comments are between 0-10...

Comment: If i remember correctly. mysql caching only works well if you have more reads on the tsblr than writes, as writes will invalidate the cached queries for that table. so if comments are being added constantly, there is no way to cache at the database.

Comment: If you will only be running it on one server, you cab use memory cache by storing the latest comments there. Snyder new comments will be inserted into the database as well as updating the mem cache. so in theory you only need to select once when the server starts.